# Convergence to supremum using Squeeze Theorem and Limit Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose that $B$ is a nonempty set of $ \mathbb{R} $ that is bounded above. Let b = sup($B$). Prove there is a sequence $b_n \in B$ that converges to b.

So I know we can use the Squeeze Theorem, and all I could think of using was the convergence theorem where we say for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ where if $N > n$, then $|b_n - b| < \epsilon$, but I didn't know how to continue from there, or whether that was how to start the proof.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What have you learned? We need to know what theorems can be used. You could use the sequence $s_n = b - \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Nothing about Cauchy, only the basics about supremum/infimum, and just started sequences and limit theorem. How did you come up with that seemingly random $s_n$?

Comment: Oh, well, because "obviously" $\lim_{n\to\infty}  b-\frac{1}{n} = b$. The trick about this type of analysis problem is that, you kinda have to "know the answer before proof"

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Is there a way to complete the proof without using a direct answer and a more general explanation to say that such a sequence exists?

Comment: Why to add "Real Analysis" in title when it is used as a tag ?

Comment: Sorry, first time posting and I forgot to remove that part when I tagged it as Real Analysis!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without losing generality, let us assume that $B = [b-1,b]$. Consider the sequence defined as $s_n = b - \frac{1}{n}$. I claim that $s_n \in B$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and $s_n$ converges to $b$.

To show that $s_n\in B$, notice that since $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\frac{1}{n} > 0$ for all $n$. As a result, $b - \frac{1}{n} < b$. This implies that $s_n \in B$ for all $n$.

To show that $s_n \to b$, for any $\epsilon>0$, we need to find $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that whenever $n\ge N$, we have $|b-s_n| < \epsilon$. Let us take out the cheat sheet:

> $$|b-s_n| = |b- b + \frac{1}{n}|=\frac{1}{n}$$
>   Can we choose $N$ such that, if $n\ge N$, then $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$? Yes. Because......?

Going back, we choose $N$ such that when $n\ge N$, we have $\frac{1}{n} \le \epsilon$. The result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Use definition of supremum. If we take $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}>0$ (you can choose any sequence that is positive and converges to zero) then there exists $b_{n}\in B$ s.t. $b_{n}>b-\frac{1}{n}$. If not, then $b_{m}\leq b-\frac{1}{n}$ for all $m$ and this implies $b-\frac{1}{n}<b$ bounds $B$, which contradicts to the fact that $b$ is supremum of $B$ (remember that supremum means least upper bound). 
So we have a sequence $b_{n}\in B$ with $b-\frac{1}{n}<b_{n}\leq b$ for each $n\geq $, and here we can use squeeze theorem to get $\lim_{n\to \infty}b_{n}=b$ (or just because of definition of convergence).